# Selecting items on a matrix based on indexes given by an array

Tags: python, arrays, list

Consider this matrix:

```
[0.9, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35],
[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.25],
[0.5, 0.45, 0.9, 0.35],
[0.2, 0.18, 0.8, 0.1],
[0.6, 0.45, 0.4, 0.9]
```

and this list:

```
[0,1,2,3,3]
```

I want to create a list that looks like the following:

```
[0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9]
```

To clarify, for each row, I want the element of the matrix whose column index is contained in the first array. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip the two lists together as below

```
a=[[0.9, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35],[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.25],[0.5, 0.45, 0.9, 0.35],[0.2, 0.18, 0.8, 0.1],[0.6, 0.45, 0.4, 0.9]]
b=[0,1,2,3,3]
[i[j] for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

Result

```
[0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9]
```

This basically pairs up each sublist in the matrix with the element of your second list in order with `zip(a,b)`

Then for each pair you choose the `b`th element of `a`

Answer (score 1):

If this is a `numpy` array, you can pass in two `numpy` arrays to access the desired indices:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0.9, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35],
[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.25],
[0.5, 0.45, 0.9, 0.35],
[0.2, 0.18, 0.8, 0.1],
[0.6, 0.45, 0.4, 0.9]])

indices = np.array([0,1,2,3,3])

data[np.arange(data.shape[0]), indices]
```

This outputs:

```py
[0.9 0.8 0.9 0.1 0.9]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 3]`, the `row` is determined by the index of the each element, and the value at that index is the `column`. This is a good case for [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
matrix = [[ ... ], [ ... ], ...] # your matrix
selections = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3]
result = [matrix[i][j] for i, j in enumerate(selections)]
```

This will be much more efficient than looping through the entire `matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through both arrays together using the [`zip`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) function.

```
def create_array_from_matrix(matrix, indices):
    if len(matrix) != len(indices):
        return None
    res = []
    for row, index in zip(matrix, indices):
        res.append(row[index])

    return res
```